# Is it possible to use hash lines instead of every single cmdline argument passed to GCC?

Tags: gcc, g++, command-line-arguments, preprocessor-directive

I use GCC for C and G++ for C++. I have trouble supplying each cmdline options everywhere.

Say I can easily replace `-DHAVE_CONFIG_H` with

```
#define HAVE_CONFIG_H
```

Are all cmdline arguments replaceable by # lines? If not, what args **are** replaceable?

I prefer at least `-O2` `-std=xxx` `-L` `-I`.

**Edit**: I'm having this problem because when I upload my code to an online judger, it would always compile it plainly (`gcc xxx.c -o xxx -lm`) and won't turn on any optimization flags for me. I can't modify their command line so I want it in my source code.

Comment: **Edit your question** to motivate it (by adding a few paragraphs). Why can't you pass appropriate compiler options (e.g. via your `Makefile`)? This seems surprising and smells a lot like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have trouble supplying each cmdline options everywhere.

Why? Are you using some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)? I believe you should use it, then it is just a matter to add a few appropriate lines in your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) (probably something like adding a line such as `CXXFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -O2 -std=c++11`)

> Are all cmdline arguments replaceable by # lines? If not, what args are replaceable?

You mean replaceable by preprocessor directives. Read [documentation of `cpp`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)

Actually, most compiler options are *not* replaceable by preprocessor directives; notably

- `-std=`
- `-L` and `-l` and any other options for the *linker*
- `-I` and similar options for include directories

However, `-O2` and *some* other optimization flags are settable by [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) e.g. `__attribute__((optimize("O2"))` (see [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html)) and by [function specific option pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html) e.g. 
`#pragma GCC optimize "-O2"`. Notice that this is specific to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

I recommend spending a few hours reading the [documentation of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/).

You might also perhaps change your [spec file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html), but I don't recommend doing that.